# SQL Rows as CheckBoxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have an employee web form where the employees can be assigned to any number of markets. I'm attempting to take the SQL row values and assign them to checkboxes in C#.

So for example my SQL database would be like the following:

```
EmployeeID  MarketID
99999       1
99999       2
99999       4
```

My code behind is

```
string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = ("usp_EmployeeMarkets");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", id);
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            Market1CheckBox.Checked = sdr["MarketID"].Equals(1);
            Market2CheckBox.Checked = sdr["MarketID"].Equals(2);
            Market3CheckBox.Checked = sdr["MarketID"].Equals(3);
            Market4CheckBox.Checked = sdr["MarketID"].Equals(4);
        }
    }
}
```

So in the example above checkboxes 1,2,4 should be checked where as checkbox 3 should not be. Obviously this isn't correct as I have done it so far as none of the checkboxes are checked. How can I accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Comment: I haven't used the SqlDataReader for a while, but are you sure you don't have to cast/parse the result of sdr["MarketID"] to an int?

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I'm getting the results of another query without issue using the same code when assigned bit values to checkboxes and text values to textboxes. The issues is when I'm attempting to take where a row column certain criteria and assign its value to a checkbox like above.

Comment: I just realized you have a logical error. Every time a row is read, you're setting all 4 checkboxes. Meaning that obviously there can never be more than 1 checkbox Checked. Instead of ".Checked = sdr...", use an If and only set it if it equals.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I was kind of wondering if that was the only way. There could be some 50+ checkboxes so was hoping to keep my code a little cleaner than 50+ if statements but if thats the only way, then I guess thats what I will need to do.

Comment: Either you could loop through all controls and check if it's typeof(Checkbox), and perform actions accordingly, OR you could write a wrapper around the Checkbox so you can add it to a List and just loop through it when reading from the database.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard posted answer with your feedback. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  List<string> listOfMarkets=new List<string>();    
   while (sdr.Read())
    {
        listOfMarkets.Add(sdr["MarketID"].ToString());
    }
        Market1CheckBox.Checked = listOfMarkets.Contains("1")?true:false;
        Market2CheckBox.Checked = listOfMarkets.Contains("2")?true:false;
        Market3CheckBox.Checked = listOfMarkets.Contains("3")?true:false;
        Market4CheckBox.Checked =listOfMarkets.Contains("4")?true:false;
```

try this it will surely work

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I ended up doing:

```
string sqlConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(sqlConn))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = ("usp_EmployeeMarkets");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", id);
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            string value = sdr["MarketID"].ToString();
            if (value == "1")
            {
                Market1CheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
            if (value == "2")
            {
                Market2CheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
            if (value == "3")
            {
                Market3CheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
            if (value == "4")
            {
                Market4CheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```